# 2 way table triggers in 2 different database but inserts, updates and deletes on a table in the 2 databases

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I have a task that I could really use some help about triggers. So here it goes. I have databases 1 and 2 let's call them db1 and db2. I now have a table named tbl_client_contact. What I want to do is create a trigger that will insert, update or delete in the said table that exists in the 2 databases. For example, I will insert values in the table in db1, I should expect those values to be inserted in the table in db 2. That I got right, but the problem is when I go do db2 and make manipulations, I cant make the values inserted in the table in db 2 to appear in the table in db 1 without something happening like an infinite loop of inserting etc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "CISTEST"."TRG_SYNC_CLIENT_CONTACT"
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TBL_CLIENT_CONTACT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.source IN ('CIS','CIC') THEN 
        IF INSERTING THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_client_contact@CVLTEST
                (seq_id,client_id,contact_type_id,contact_no,default_tag,
                 source,status_id,post_by,post_date,last_update_by,
                 last_update)        
            VALUES
                (:NEW.seq_id,:NEW.client_id,:NEW.contact_type_id ,:NEW.contact_no,:NEW.default_tag,
                 :NEW.source,:NEW.status_id,:NEW.post_by,:NEW.post_date,:NEW.last_update_by,
                 :NEW.last_update);              
                 COMMIT;

        ELSIF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE tbl_client_contact@CVLTEST
            SET contact_type_id = :NEW.contact_type_id,
                contact_no = :NEW.contact_no,
                default_tag = :NEW.default_tag,
                source = :NEW.source,
                status_id = :NEW.status_id,
                last_update_by = :NEW.last_update_by,
                last_update = :NEW.last_update
             WHERE seq_id = :OLD.seq_id;             
             COMMIT;

        ELSIF DELETING THEN
            DELETE FROM tbl_client_contact@CVLTEST 
            WHERE seq_id = :OLD.seq_id;         
            COMMIT;

        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

I also have an almost the same trigger in db 2. The thing is, when I disable the trigger in db 2, trigger in db 1 works just fine. But when I enable trigger in db2, my desired output just won't work. Help anyone?

Comment: You could work around this by having different schema names from the dblink to the object owning schemas. Eg. If the objects are in schema1 on both db1 and db2, and the dblinks connect as schema2 (with the appropriate privileges etc), then you could include a check in the trigger to make sure that it only executes if the user is schema1.